# Polymer 1.0 How to lazy render dom-repeat

Tags: polymer-1.0

I have a pretty large dom-repeat that takes 10 seconds to fully render on screen. Is there anyway to render part of dom-repeat, step-by-step until it is fully rendered?

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{itemList}}">
  <span>{{item}}</span>
</template>
```

The list is about 16000 entries long, so long because in my app it is a triple nested dom-repeat. I use this to render `paper-menu` and `paper-submenu`

Comment: You should use an [`iron-list`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-list) to render only the viewport-visible subset of items.

Comment: @tony19 Thanks! Though I should specify that I'm rendering this with `paper-menu` and `paper-submenu`. Each menu item has submenus, total of 3 layers. That's why it takes so long. You'd think that `paper-submenu` should lazy load only viewport-visible items but apparently they dont :(

Comment: 16000 items in a menu seems awfully high, and probably a UX issue. In any case, you could probably dynamically load the menu items (on expanding a menu item or as you scroll).

Comment: Totally agree! If there is no existing utility function to lazy load `paper-submenu` then I'll implement a dynamic loading function.

Comment: Did you try [this](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/dom-repeat#property-initialCount)?

Answer (score -1):

A polymer pagination component can help you.
Have a look into polymer pagination component in
[customelements.io](https://customelements.io/foohyfooh/pagination-table/) or 
[mercury-paginator](https://github.com/bquarks/mercury-paginator)